# One liner required, pref UNIX-based, for variation of JOIN command

Tags: unix, join, awk

I need a one-liner (that I can put in a dos batch file), preferably using a unix command like AWK or JOIN. The function I need is essentially a more elaborate version of the following JOIN command:

```
join -j 1 -a 1 file1.txt file2.txt -t "^" > output.txt
```

[walkthrough: field separators are "^", join key is 1st field of both fields, and not exactly sure what the "-a 1" is doing exactly but it is sticking the bit-to-be joined on the end of the row of the other file, which is what I want.

Now, this one-liner works fine where both files are sorted and there is only one matching line in the 2nd file ... but I need it to try to match up to 4 lines in the 2nd file.

```
E.g.
file1:

12^blahblah
13^blahblahblahblah
14^blahblahblahblahblahblahblahblah

file2:

12^banana
12^orange
12^apple
13^potato
14^tomato
```

So I want the output like this:

```
12^blahblah^banana,orange,apple
13^blahblahblahblah^potato
14^blahblahblahblahblahblahblahblah^tomato
```

[Doesn't have to be a comma separating the new items]

Comment: wrt `Doesn't have to be a comma separating the new items` - Why bring up commas at all? Have you had a problem in the past with commands spuriously injecting commas in your text?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try this `awk` command:

```
awk -F'^' 'NR==FNR{if($1 in a){a[$1]=a[$1]","$2} else {a[$1]=$2}} NR>FNR{print $0 "^" a[$1]}' file2 file1
```

The script fills an array `a` with the content of `file2` and and append the content of the array when parsing `file1`

Answer (score 1):

```
$ awk -F'^' 'NR==FNR{a[$1]=$0 FS;next} {a[$1] = a[$1] s[$1] $2; s[$1]=","} END{for (i in a) print a[i]}' file1 file2
12^blahblah^banana,orange,apple
13^blahblahblahblah^potato
14^blahblahblahblahblahblahblahblah^tomato
```

Comment: Although this code may help to solve the problem, it doesn't explain _why_ and/or _how_ it answers the question. Providing this additional context  would significantly improve its long-term value. Please [edit] your answer to add explanation, including what limitations and assumptions apply.